# Bootstrap modal load php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I have the table, it display as name, last name, edit certain user, how would I do this?

I was using the facebox and now shifting to bootstrap;

in my admin.php page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.load-modal').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#myModal2').modal('show');
});
</script>
.... some code ....
echo '<td><a class="load-modal" href="editadminprofile.php?id='.$row['id'].'" data-toggle="modal1" data-target="#myModal2" title="Click To View Orders">Edit Profile</a></td>';
```

It just takes me to the target page instead of opening the modal.

EditAdminProfile.php

```
<?php
include('../connect.php');
$id=$_GET['id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin where id='$id'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $idnum=$row['idnum'];
    $password=$row['password'];
    $fname=$row['fname'];
    $lname=$row['lname'];
    $mname=$row['mname'];
    $birth=$row['birth'];
    $status=$row['status'];
    $gender=$row['gender'];
  }
?>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal1">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><center>Create new administrator</center></h4>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `data-toggle` and `data-dismiss` should have the value `modal`.

2.Your modal section should be in your admin.php page.

admin.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.load-modal').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#myModal2').modal('show');
});
</script>
.... some code ....
echo '<td><a class="load-modal" href="editadminprofile.php?id='.$row['id'].'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" title="Click To View Orders">Edit Profile</a></td>';

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
              <!-- HTML will be inserted here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

3. Bootstrap will load `editadminprofile.php` into `<div class="modal-content"></div>`, so you have to move your `.modal-header` codes inside `editadminprofile.php`

editadminprofile.php

```
<?php
include('../connect.php');
$id=$_GET['id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin where id='$id'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $idnum=$row['idnum'];
    $password=$row['password'];
    $fname=$row['fname'];
    $lname=$row['lname'];
    $mname=$row['mname'];
    $birth=$row['birth'];
    $status=$row['status'];
    $gender=$row['gender'];
  }
?>

    <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><center>Create new administrator</center></h4>
                </div>
```

If I were you I will first set `href="#"` to test if the modal works (a blank modal), then put the href back and see if editadminprofile.php is correctly loaded.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you haven't included `editadminprofile.php`, and I think it's throwing error as expected parameters are not passed.

When you click on `Edit Profile` button, and expect to see Modal. At the same time Bootstrap looks for Modal body on the same page, and in your case it's not found.

`editadminprofile.php?id='.$row['id']` seems your Modal is dynamic, so you can call ajax to get modal on same page.

- You additionally need a div on same page.

  `<div id="ajax-response"></div>`
- Add a class on all anchors, on which you need to show modal. (you might have it multiple, as it seems to be dynamic.)

  `echo '<td><a class="load-modal" href="editadminprofile.php?id='.$row['id'].'" data-toggle="modal1" data-target="#myModal2" title="Click To View Orders">Edit Profile</a></div></td>';`
- Write ajax which calls, which is binded to `.load-modal` class, will trigger `onclick`, and on success after putting modal body in `ajax-response` div, you need to show modal using `$('#myModal').modal('show');` (**change `#myModal` with your actual modal id**)

  ```
  $('.load-modal').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var url = $(this).attr('attr');

      $.ajax({
         url: url,
         type: 'post',
         async: false,
         success: function(response){
              $('#ajax-response').html(response);
              $('#myModal').modal('show');
         }
      })
  });
  ```

**UPDATE**
There is a problem with the placement of your script. Problem? class `load-modal` was not added to the document before it called `$('.load-modal')`.

Move your script down, anywhere after `<td><a class="load-modal" ...`, or if you don't want to change position, you may wrap it in [`jQuery(document).ready(function()){`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/). See your updated code snippet below:

```
.... some code ....
echo '<td><a class="load-modal" href="editadminprofile.php?id='.$row['id'].'" data-toggle="modal1" data-target="#myModal2" title="Click To View Orders">Edit Profile</a></td>';

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.load-modal').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#myModal2').modal('show');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your post. I have a question, do I edit the url? I tried your steps, seems like the modal is not loading. I changed the name `myModal`

Comment: Okay, there might be problem in your modal body, post your `editadminprofile.php` code

Comment: Check the update post. I add the editadminprofile.php. It won't open modal for some reason.

Comment: `$('#myModal').modal('show');` should be `$('#myModal2').modal('show');`, also there is an extra div closing `Edit Profile</a></div></td>`, fix that too.

now it should work, See fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/3bfs6e5q/1/

Comment: Okay, it's getting there. When I click it, it just takes me to the page instead of opening up the modal.

Comment: hmm.. something you are missing! `e.preventDefault();` will stop default action. In case of anchor it will stop, to go to target page.

Comment: I included that, it just takes me to the target page instead of opening the modal.

Comment: I used your updated code, it doesn't do anything. If I put it back, it just takes me to the target page.

Comment: rollback to the code, I suggested. and look for errors in console, your code (previous one) will not work any way, event is not trapped and due to that it's redirecting to target page